Three.js Context Lost Error and Performance Issues with Multiple 3D Animations in Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js project where I’m using Three.js to render multiple 3D animations. However, I'm facing two main issues:

The 3D animations are not showing up correctly, and the console logs the error: THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.
I'm experiencing performance issues, likely due to the multiple 3D animations

https://sinanptm.vercel.app
https://github.com/sinanptm/portfolio
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Ensured that each 3D model has optimized textures and geometries.
Attempted to control rendering updates manually.
Questions:

How can I improve performance when rendering multiple 3D animations in Three.js within Next.js?
Are there best practices or common pitfalls to avoid context loss in scenarios like this?

